# Signing certificate with root certificate (CA) works but the new signed certificate has no extensions

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, x509certificate, signing

this is my first question. I have worked on the problem several days and given up, so i hope you can help me.

I wrote an application in C# that can create a certificate with extensions (alternativ domainname, extensions for signing etc.) and import it in the Windows Certificate Store. The most of the functions are Marshaled from Crypt32.dll like CertCreateSelfSignCertificate and everything works.

My next task is to sign a certificate with a self created certificate authority. So i used the CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate to create a signed certificate. It works to created a signed certificate but it has no extensions and no private key.

This is the function that should make the magic.

```
public static X509Certificate2 SignCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificateToSign, int KeySpecification, X509Certificate2 CACert)
            {
                IntPtr hCAProv = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr hProvAllocPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr subordinateCertInfoAllocPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

                RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();

                try
                {
                    // Get CA cert into CERT_CONTEXT
                    // Get CA cert into CERT_INFO from context.pCertInfo

                    NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT CAContext = (NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(CACert.Handle, typeof(NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT));
                    NativeMethods.CERT_INFO CACertInfo = (NativeMethods.CERT_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(CAContext.pCertInfo, typeof(NativeMethods.CERT_INFO));

                    uint pcbData = 0;

                    // get the context property handle of the CA Cert

                    if (!NativeMethods.CertGetCertificateContextProperty(CACert.Handle, 2, hProvAllocPtr, ref pcbData))
                        throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    hProvAllocPtr = NativeMethods.LocalAlloc(0, new IntPtr((long)pcbData));

                    if (!NativeMethods.CertGetCertificateContextProperty(CACert.Handle, 2, hProvAllocPtr, ref pcbData))
                        throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER signatureAlgo = new CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER()
                    {
                        pszObjId = NativeMethods.OID_RSA_SHA256RSA
                    };

                    // get the key handle of the CA Cert

                    CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO pKeyInfo = (CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(hProvAllocPtr, typeof(CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO));

                    // Acquire a context to the provider for crypto

                    if (!NativeMethods.CryptAcquireContext(ref hCAProv, pKeyInfo.ContainerName, pKeyInfo.ProviderName, pKeyInfo.ProviderType, pKeyInfo.Flags))
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    // Get subordinate cert into CERT_CONTEXT
                    // Get subordinate cert into CERT_INFO from context.pCertInfo

                    NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT subordinateCertContext = (NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(certificateToSign.Handle, typeof(NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT));
                    NativeMethods.CERT_INFO subordinateCertInfo = (NativeMethods.CERT_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(subordinateCertContext.pCertInfo, typeof(NativeMethods.CERT_INFO));

                    IntPtr extensions = CreateExtensionsStructure(certificateToSign.Extensions);

                    subordinateCertInfo.cExtension = certificateToSign.Extensions == null ? 0 : (uint)certificateToSign.Extensions.Count;
                    subordinateCertInfo.rgExtension = extensions;

                    subordinateCertInfo.SignatureAlgorithm = signatureAlgo;
                    subordinateCertInfo.Issuer = CACertInfo.Subject;

                    subordinateCertInfoAllocPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.CERT_INFO)));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(subordinateCertInfo, subordinateCertInfoAllocPtr, false);

                    byte[] pbEncodedCert = null;
                    UInt32 pbEncodedCertLength = 0;

                      if (!NativeMethods.CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate(hCAProv,
                                                                    (uint)KeySpecification,
                                                                    NativeMethods.X509_ASN_ENCODING,
                                                                    NativeMethods.X509_CERT_TO_BE_SIGNED,
                                                                    subordinateCertInfoAllocPtr,
                                                                    ref signatureAlgo,
                                                                    IntPtr.Zero,
                                                                    pbEncodedCert,
                                                                    ref pbEncodedCertLength))
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }

                    pbEncodedCert = new byte[pbEncodedCertLength];

                    if (!NativeMethods.CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate(hCAProv,
                                                                    (uint)KeySpecification,
                                                                    NativeMethods.X509_ASN_ENCODING,
                                                                    NativeMethods.X509_CERT_TO_BE_SIGNED,
                                                                    subordinateCertInfoAllocPtr,
                                                                    ref signatureAlgo,
                                                                    IntPtr.Zero,
                                                                    pbEncodedCert,
                                                                    ref pbEncodedCertLength))
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }

                    X509Certificate2 signedCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pbEncodedCert, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

                    return signedCertificate;
                }
```

An other question is why don't i get the extensions of the given certificate from the CERT_INFO

```
NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT subordinateCertContext = (NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(certificateToSign.Handle, typeof(NativeMethods.CERT_CONTEXT));
NativeMethods.CERT_INFO subordinateCertInfo = (NativeMethods.CERT_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(subordinateCertContext.pCertInfo, typeof(NativeMethods.CERT_INFO));
```

By the way if i use the subordinateCertInfo directly in CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate as pvStructInfo the new certificate has the extensions but it will not have the connection to the CA. Because the subordinateCertInfo.Issuer was not set.

```
[DllImport(CRYPT32, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate(IntPtr hCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
                                                        uint dwKeySpec,
                                                        uint dwCertEncodingType,
                                                        ulong lpszStructType,
                                                        IntPtr pvStructInfo,
                                                        ref CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER pSignatureAlgorithm,
                                                        IntPtr pvHashAuxInfo,
                                                        byte[] pbEncoded,
                                                        ref uint pcbEncoded);
```

By the way no i don't want to use Bouncy Castle or write the application in C++. So i hope you have a solution without some extrem changes.

Comment: If some information is needed just ask about it.

Comment: I would recommend to use specialized CA software to handle all these tasks. Get CA and move on. Writing your own CA software is not the smartest thing you can do these days especially when there are really good ones, like Microsoft ADCS or Java's EJBCA.

Comment: Can you give some arguments for using them and which one?

Comment: If you are using Windows, then Microsoft ADCS will greatly fit your needs. Arguments? In short: CA duties are not only in encoding and signing other certificates. It has to maintain a lot of other things, data validation, database maintenance, CRL publication, policy enforcement and so on. It is hard to get it manually or by writing your own code. This is why you should specialized software.

Comment: Okay i will look at ADCS.

Comment: But it would be interesting to find out why the extensions disappear or don't get exportet out of the CERT_INFO